# Finding the webroot directory for Ghost in AWS

Tags: aws, letsencrypt

I installed Ghost via Bitnami on AWS and registered a domain (750in100.com) from Google Domains with it. Next I tried installing an SSL certificate through Let's Encrypt, and that's where I'm running into trouble.

When going through the guided process launched by

> $ sudo certbot certonly

I find myself confused when it prompts me to select the webroot. I've tried locations like:

/opt/bitnami/apps/ghost/htdocs

and

/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf

but apparently I don't understand exactly where is the webroot directory which certbot needs to know to proceed. I get an error each time like this:

> Failed authorization procedure. 750in100.com (http-01):
>   urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient
>   authorization :: Invalid response from
>   http://750in100.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/[long stream of
>   seemingly random characters]

and so on. At the end of the "important notes" for the errors:

> To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
>   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain contain(s)
>   the right IP address.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening that URL in your web browser to verify that you're getting a 404 error as expected.

Then use `sudo find / -iname "*htdocs*"` or similar (index.html, bitnami, etc.) to find the path. Try finding bitnami's `config.*.json` and see if the path is in there.

Comment: Sorry, I sent the comment before I was ready.

750in100.com and www.750in100.com load just fine in my web browser (Firefox); no 404s.

I've now tried:
/opt/bitnami/apps/ghost/htdocs
/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs
/opt/bitnami/apps/bitnami/banner/htdocs
/home/bitnami/htdocs

and got the same result every time (failure).

While hunting around for config.*.json (find didn't work), I found config.example.js (along with several other .js and a couple of .json and .md files - as well as a few subdirectories) inside /opt/bitnami/apps/ghost/htdocs. Could that be relevant?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/apache/#how-to-install-the-lets-encrypt-client